# how to get data from a form in angularjs/express app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

Hi guys may i know how to get data from a form in angularjs/express app ? 
for example

**index.js routes**

```
app.post('/register', sessionHandler.handleSignup);
```

**handleSignup function**

is there any way to get the data without using `req.body` ? because angularjs prevent me submit the form so i have to think another way to get the data.

```
 this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";

        var email = req.body.email,
         confirmEmail = req.body.confirmEmail,
         password = req.body.password,
         confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword,
         firstName = req.body.firstName,
         lastName = req.body.lastName,
         penName = req.body.penName,
         publicUsername = req.body.publicUsername;

        // set these up in case we have an error case
        var errors = {'email': email,'publicUsername': publicUsername,'firstName': firstName,'lastName': lastName,'penName': penName};
        if (validateSignup(publicUsername, password, confirmPassword, email, confirmEmail, errors)) {
            users.addUser(email, password, firstName, lastName, penName, publicUsername, function(err, user) {
                "use strict";

                if (err) {
                    // this was a duplicate
                    if (err.code == '11000') {
                        errors['email_error'] = "Email already in use. Please choose another";
                        return res.render("register", errors);
                    }
                    // this was a different error
                    else {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                }

                sessions.startSession(user['_id'], function(err, session_id) {
                    "use strict";

                    if (err) return next(err);

                    res.cookie('session', session_id);
                    return res.redirect('/');
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log("user did not validate");
            return res.render("register", errors);
        }
    }
```

**controller** ( is there any way to make the page stay at the same page if there is an error ? if no error then redirect to "/")

```
function RegisterCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.submitPost = function() {
    $http.post('/register', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      });
  };
}
```

**my form**

```html
<div class="pure-u-1 text-center">
  <form method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><h1 class="pure-splash-subhead midnightblue"><span class='lightblue'>Join</span> us today and start write things that <span class='maroon'>matter</span></h1>
      </legend>
      <p class="text-center red">{{email_error}}</p>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input required name="email" ng-model="form.email" class="pure-u-1-3" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <p class="text-center red">{{confirmEmail_error}}</p>
        <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm Email Address</label>
        <input required name="confirmEmail" ng-model="form.confirmEmail" class="pure-u-1-3" type="email" placeholder="Confirm Email Address">
      </div>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <p class="text-center red">{{password_error}}</p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input required name="password" ng-model="form.password" class="pure-u-1-3" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <p class="text-center red">{{confirmPassword_error}}</p>
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input required name="confirmPassword" ng-model="form.confirmPassword" class="pure-u-1-3" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input required name="firstName" class="pure-u-1-3" ng-model="form.firstName" type="text" placeholder="Your first name">
      </div>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input required name="lastName" class="pure-u-1-3" ng-model="form.lastName" type="text" placeholder="and your last name">
      </div>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="penName"><abbr title="A pen name">Nom de plume</abbr></label>
        <input required name="penName" ng-model="form.penName" class="pure-u-1-3" type="text" placeholder="Pen Name eg:J.R.R. Tolkien">
      </div>
      <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="publicUsername">Public Username</label>
        <input required name="publicUsername" class="pure-u-1-3" type="text"  ng-model="form.publicUsername" placeholder="Username eg:gandalf">
        <p class="pure-splash-subhead">https://www.HoneyBooBoo.com/@<b class="maroon">{{form.publicUsername}}</b></p>
        <p class="text-center red">{{publicUsername_error}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1 ">
        <label for="conAndTerm" class="pure-checkbox">
          <input id="conAndTerm" type="checkbox"> I've read the <a class='link blue'href="#">terms and conditions</a>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' ng-click="submitPost()" class="pure-button pure-button-secondary pure-u-1-3" value="Register">
        <br/>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are confusing Angular's single-page-app (SPA) concept with the traditional server based model. With an SPA, the server doesn't do any redirecting or serve HTML. Your server sends JSON, and Angular then renders all the pages client-side.

It looks likely that the request object is not being passed correctly to your server-side registration function, and that is why you cannot access req.body. Your Angular code looks correct.

I am going to give you some code from my own project that does exactly what you want.

**Inside your index.js routes**

```
var signup = require('./routes/signup');
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    signup(req, res);
});
```

**routes/signup.js**

```js
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  validateSignup(req.body, function(error, data) {
    if(error) {
      res.send(400, error.message);
    } else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  })
}

function validateSignup(data, callback) {
  // All your validation logic goes here
  if(success) callback(null, newuser);
  else callback(new Error('Registration failed!'), null);
}
```

**Your html file in the public directory**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Sample Registration Page</title>
    <link href="styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="SignupCtrl">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="User.username" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="User.password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="register()">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**And finally register.js**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

  $scope.User = {};
  $scope.errorMessage = '';

  $scope.register = function() {
    $http.post('/signup', $scope.User).
    success(function(data) {
      $location.path('/');
    }).error(function(err) {
      $scope.errorMessage = err;
    });
  }
});
```

I've tested it, and as long as you fill in all your signup logic on the server-side correctly, it should work for you also. Note: for the redirect to work properly, you will need to set up your Angular routing and create a page to redirect to.

Comment: hey Colin do you mind to explain "you will need to set up your Angular routing and create a page to redirect to."  to me ? thank you

Comment: Hi John, you can see this tutorial on setting up your routes:
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Here is an even better tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 3):

in your angular controller you can use the data inside `ng-model="form.email"` with `$scope.form.email`

then you can send that to your nodejs app with a http request or other like websockets.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `ng-app` in your app. Then to handle the data use `ng-model`.

your template input field should have the data model to handle the data.

Like for email

```
<input required name="email" class="pure-u-1-3" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="form.email">
```

Comment: i already have the ng-app in my app , the problem is how to get the data from this form and pass it to **handleSignup** because i want to do validation over there and insert into my database as well

Comment: I have given that in answer. In angular ng-model is used to handle the data. So for each field assign ng-model="field-name".

Comment: sorry i just realized i didn't copy paste the latest code to the question sorry my bad, actually i did what you mentioned in the answer but the question how to get the data from the form one by one like req.body.email i can get email data but in angularjs way

Comment: 'var email = req.body.email' how to get data from angular and replace req.body.email

Comment: on submit use ng-click="submitPost()"

Comment: hi @Jayram, I already replace the suggestion you given.However when i click submit it directly link me to '/' without any validation, because i have validation function in my handleSignup which require data from the form and my question is how to get the data from the form and pass it into (var email) now i have [var email=req.body.email] this is get the data directly from the form but how about in angular.js way ? [[ $http.post('/register', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      }); ]] how do i get the "data" and pass it into my handleSignup function